# file $(ls /usr/bin/* | grep zip) command gives me errors. What's wrong?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards, command-substitution

I decided to read a book about Linux/Unix.
I've reached a chapter where they try to explain how to pass the output of commands as expansions to the shell.

The following command

`file $(ls /usr/bin/* | grep zip)`

gives me the error "cannot open "file name (No such file or directory)".
On the contrary, when I do

`file $(ls | grep zip)`

everything appears normally, no matter the folder. Why? Is it some kind of argument restriction?

If I do this

`file $(ls Pictures/ | grep jpg)`

I get the following:

`1234.jpg: ERROR: cannot open 1234.jpg (No such file or directory)`

while moving right in the directory that I want to list

`nassosdim@ubuntu:~$ cd Pictures/`

`nassosdim@ubuntu:~/Pictures$ file $(ls | grep jpg)`

prints out the result of file

`1234.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01`

Can someone explain to me what's going on? :(

Comment: It would help if you also said *what* errors you get.

Comment: Apologies, added.

Comment: Turns out that ls with a directory as an argument results in file names and not the actual paths. Plus as @Caleb pointed out, parsing the output of ls is bad. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is coming because bash is trying to expand the `*` in your argument to ls using glob pattern matching. It will always through such an error when the glob doesn't match the pattern. The `*` then gets passed to `ls` as a real asterisk, which doesn't match a file either so `ls` will error!

There are several bits about what you are doing that are redundant. I know you are trying to learn a construct, but let's break down some of the bits of what you just accomplished and how it could have been done.

1. `ls /usr/bin` is sufficient to list files in the bin directory, you don't need the star at all.
2. You should never [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at all, it is ambiguous and potentially dangerous.
3. You could get the same effect without grep by doing `ls /usr/bin/*zip*`, but the `ls` is still redundant, you can just pass the glob expantion to file: `file /usr/bin/*zip*`

Lastly, `find` is usually a better tool for finding files. You could do what you are after like this:

```
$ find /usr/bin -iname '*zip*' -exec file {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell expands the `*` and turns the command into `file $(ls /usr/bin/a /usr/bin/b /usr/bin/whatever | grep zip)`.  You don't need to specify a asterisk in UNIX unless you want the shell to expand it to include everything before it passes it to the `ls`.

i.e. your shell replaces the * with every matching file *before* it runs the command, which is not how it works on Windows if you're used to that.

[Read section 3.4.9 here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

```
file $(ls /usr/bin/ | grep zip)
```

is the right way to do it (right in the sense that you don't need the *, but see Caleb's answer for other issues and options).  But note, that actually runs,

```
file /usr/bin/a /usr/bin/b /usr/bin/whatever
```

not

```
file /usr/bin/a
file /usr/bin/b
file /usr/bin/whatever
```

again, it doesn't do it the way windows does.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `ls /usr/bin/* | grep zip` to see what arguments you are feeding to `file`. I was baffled by the result a bit. On my Ubuntu system, the result is this:

```
/usr/bin/funzip
/usr/bin/gpg-zip
/usr/bin/mzip
/usr/bin/preunzip
/usr/bin/prezip
/usr/bin/prezip-bin
/usr/bin/unzip
/usr/bin/unzipsfx
/usr/bin/zip
/usr/bin/zipcloak
/usr/bin/zipgrep
/usr/bin/zipinfo
/usr/bin/zipnote
/usr/bin/zipsplit
funzip
gpg-zip
mzip
preunzip
prezip
prezip-bin
unzip
unzipsfx
zip
zipcloak
zipgrep
zipinfo
zipnote
zipsplit
```

Using `ls /usr/bin/* | less` we can see why we get that result: after all the files in /usr/bin, `ls` also lists the contents of the /usr/bin/X11 directory, and it lists them without the directory names prepended.

And when you feed these file names without a directory name to `file`, `file` cannot find these files and you get the "No such file or directory" error messages (as a side note: if you get error messages, please don't just say "I got errors", but post the error messages).

Like Caleb already posted, just use `file /usr/bin/*zip*`.

Comment: I apologize about the formatting of my question, this is the first time that I'm posting and realized that I expressed it vaguely so I did the necessary editing.

Comment: @Nassosdim: thank you for making the question clearer (and a screenshot really isn't necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the results of `ls` can be a risky business as the output format varies. You'd be better doing something like this:

```
file /path/to/*.zip
```

Try a simpler command to demonstrate how process substitution works:

```
ls $(echo /usr/bin)
```